# Help me solve this (∀x)[Px⇔(∀y)[Qxy⇔¬Qyy]]⇒(∀x)[¬Px] first order logic (step by step)

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This is a MCQ of a competitive exam(GATE)  , defined below . I found many different -2 explanation in market books and many other sources , but there is conflict between each explanation , I found all option correct by that different sources , I confused ,finally , I need explanation for this MCQ.

**Problem is :**

> Consider the following formula and its two interpretations I1 and I2.
>
> ```
>          α:(∀x)[Px⇔(∀y)[Qxy⇔¬Qyy]]⇒(∀x)[¬Px]
> ```
>
> I1 : Domain: the set of natural numbers
>
> Px = 'x is a prime number'
>
> Qxy = 'y divides x'
>
> I2 : same as I1 except
>   that Px = 'x is a composite number'.
>
> Which of the following statements is true?
>
> (A) I1 satisfies α, I2 does not
>     (B) I2 satisfies α, I1 does not
>
> (C) Neither I1 nor I2 satisfies α
>    (D) Both I1 and I2 satisfies α

**One explanation is :**

> α in words: LHS implies RHS, where for I1
>
> LHS = If for all x, x is prime if and only if for all y, y is a factor
>   of x if and only if y does not divide itself. In other words, for all
>   x, if x is prime, x cannot have any factor and if x is not having any
>   factor then x is prime. RHS = All x are non-prime
>
> Here LHS is always TRUE but RHS is not true as domain of x is set of
>   natural numbers and hence x cannot be always not prime. So, α is not
>   satisfiable for I1.
>
> Now for I2,
>
> LHS = If for all x, x is composite if and only if for all y, y is a
>   factor of x if and only if y does not divide itself. In other words,
>   for all x, if x is composite, x cannot have any factor and if x is not
>   having any factor then x is composite. RHS = All x are non-composite
>
> Here, LHS can never be true. x can either be prime or composite. If x
>   is composite, P(x) is true but the right side of double implication is
>   false. If x is prime, P(x) is false, but right side of double
>   implication is true. So, the double implication never returns TRUE
>   making LHS of α always FALSE. So, α becomes TRUE irrespective of RHS
>   and I2 is satisfiable.

**another solution is :**

> First of all, note that, in α, ¬Qyy is always false, because every
>   number divides itself. Also not that rightmost formula (∀x)[¬Px] is
>   always false, because clearly it is not the case that every number is
>   not the prime number (in case of I1), nor it is the case that every
>   number is not the composite number (in case of I2). Also note that,
>   variable x in this expression is not same as variable x in leftside
>   expression, they are independent. In fact, we can rewrite α as
>   α:(∀x)[Px⇔(∀y)[Qxy⇔¬Qyy]]⇒(∀z)[¬Pz].  Let us consider I1 first. So let
>   us assign some value to x, and see if it satisfies α. We can partition
>   assignments of x into 3 parts : when x is prime, when x is composite,
>   when x is 1.
>
> When x is prime : Px is true, also Qxy is false for all y except 1,
>   because only 1 divides x. So formula Qxy⇔¬Qyy is true for all y except
>   1, but due to ∀y outside this, whole formula ∀y[Qxy⇔¬Qyy] becomes
>   false, because it would have been true if Qxy⇔¬Qyy was true for every
>   y.  So now (∀x)[Px⇔(∀y)[Qxy⇔¬Qyy]] becomes false. So whole α becomes
>   true. When x is composite : Px is false, also Qxy is true for some y
>   (which divide x), and false for some y (which do not divide x), so
>   Qxy⇔¬Qyy becomes true for some y and false for some y, but again due
>   to ∀y outside, ∀y[Qxy⇔¬Qyy] becomes false.  So (∀x)[Px⇔(∀y)[Qxy⇔¬Qyy]]
>   becomes true, and so α becomes false. So for some x, I1 satisfies α,
>   but for some, it doesn't, so overall, it doesn't satisfies α. Note
>   that we don't need to look into case of x=1, because we already know
>   the answer. Now consider I2. Here Px means x is composite. Again we
>   look into same cases as above :
>
> When x is prime : Px is false, also ∀y[Qxy⇔¬Qyy] becomes false because
>   of same reasons as above.  So now (∀x)[Px⇔(∀y)[Qxy⇔¬Qyy]] becomes
>   true. So whole α becomes false. So clearly I2 also doesn't satisfy α.
>   Again we won't go into other cases, as we already got false for some
>   x. So Neither I1 nor I2 satisfies α, so option (C) is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the problem is stated, the correct answer is: (D) both I1 and I2 satisfies α.

Let us look in the details.

First note that α  can be rewritten as

α:(∀x)[Px⇔(∀y)[Qxy⇔¬Qyy]]⇒(∀z)[¬Pz]

1. Let us look at I1.

Take any prime number x, so Px is TRUE, but since $1$ and x divides x, and both $1$ and x divide themselves respectively, we have that (∀y)[Qxy⇔¬Qyy] is FALSE. So (∀x)[Px⇔(∀y)[Qxy⇔¬Qyy]] is FALSE. and so α is true in I1. It means I1 satisfies α.

2. Let us look at I2.

Take any composite number x, so Px is TRUE, but since $1$ and x divides x, and both $1$ and x divide themselves respectively, we have that (∀y)[Qxy⇔¬Qyy] is FALSE. So (∀x)[Px⇔(∀y)[Qxy⇔¬Qyy]] is FALSE. and so α is true in I2. It means I2 satisfies α.

So, both I1 and I2 satisfies α.

Comment: Thanks for clear my doubt :)